# Dot matrix display in Cycles?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, materials

Is it possible to make a [dot matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_matrix#LED_matrix) look with cycles?

I attempted this with the following node setup:

[image]

However, the dots should be round, and each dot should only have one color. As you can see, this is not the case:

[image]

This was possible in BI with a technique described on the [wiki](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.4/Manual/Materials/Halos#Dotmatrix_display).

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

How about something like this?

[image: Dot matrix example]

Or, even more fun:

[image: Glowing dotmatrix – what could be better!]

Or a ball:

[image: So much fun]

Or a tribute to the question author:

[image: Yet another "example"]

(I am having way too much fun with this)

The dot aspect ratio depends on your UV unwrap, so you can customize it as you want. I have gotten them to be square on a non-square image, but having a square image makes it a lot easier.
Workflow:

1. Identify the nearest hole.
2. Find the distance to the hole.
3. If the distance is greater than the radius, use transparent. Otherwise, use the central color of the center of the hole.

**EDIT:** GitHub user **[@JayFoxRox](https://github.com/JayFoxRox)** has [kindly
suggested](https://github.com/wchargin/wchargin.github.io/issues/1) some helpful simplifications to the below node
setup. Instead of computing distance by taking the square root of the
sum of the squares of components, simply compute squared distance by
taking the dot product of the two inputs via the Vector Math node.
(Then, of course, compare this to the squared radius instead of the raw
radius.) And the “Combine Vector” and “Separate Vector” node groups now
exist as first-class “Combine XYZ” and “Separate XYZ”, anyway. Thanks!

Blendfile: [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0g0qossrgw5gzia/DotMatrix.blend), [Blend-Exchange](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/4578/).

**Usage:**

[image: How to use this node group]

**Main node setup** (right-click → *Open Image in New Tab* to see larger)**:**

[image: Main node group, "DotMatrix"]

**Separation (top) and combination (bottom):** (would be nicer if it were built-in)

[image: Node groups "Separate Vector" (top) and "Combine Vector" (bottom)]

**Distance:** (Pythagorean theorem/Euclidean norm)

[image: Node group "Distance"]

Comment: @Mentalist: Thanks for rehosting the link.

Comment: Great job, very useful could I ask a question? How can change the number of dot matrix?
Thanks in advance
france

Comment: @france Have you tried playing with the "spacing" and "radius" inputs?