# Can I get the object dimensions in Cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor

Can I get these dimensions:

[image: Dimensions]
<sup>(bpy.data.objects['Cube'].dimensions)</sup>

in a Cycles node, as a vector?

I tried an *Attribute* node with `dimensions[0]` as the *Name*, but this didn't work. I also looked at the *Geometry* and *Object Info* nodes, but couldn't find anything that looked promising.

Preferably without Python due to the whole "trusted blendfile" feature.

This would open tons of possibilities for optimizations, such as automatically adjusting the scale of [a procedurally generated material (here, the dots are non-square)](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/3492/372).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Well, I can answer part of the question. You can get the *values* of the dimensions into cycles by using drivers, driving 3 separate **Value** nodes and using the data path of `dimensions[0]` as the driving value:

1. Add a Value node: *Add*> *Input*> *Value*
2. Right click the value and choose 'Add Driver'.
3. Change to the graph editor and change to 'Drivers' mode from the header toolbar.
4. Use the following settings in the Property panel (<kbd>N</kbd>) after selecting the channel on the left:

[image]

As you already identified the data path you need is `dimensions[0]` (0, 1, or 2).

This will result in:

[image]

(6.399 simply being the X dimension value of my test cube)

Repeat this for the 2 other dimension values and 2 more value nodes.

However, as to how you would combine 3 value nodes into a *vector* is something I don't know. You could of course drive something other than a 'Value' node using this method if that is more useful.

---

**Edit:** As noted by Chebhou, in the comments, as of Blender 2.72 a "Combine XYZ" node exists:

[image]

Instead of driving 3 individual 'Value' nodes, you can now drive the x, y and z values of the 'Combine XYZ' node which will result in a vector.

Comment: Never thought of using drivers to get external data, nice! You might be able to make a vector by doing some fancy maths with the object coordinates, but it won't be too simple I think.

Comment: Pretty nice solution. You could eliminate the Python by changing *Scripted Expression* to *Sum Values*. However, this material would just be compatible with a single object, then, right? (by the way, I use the *Combine RGB* node to create a vector, even though I always feel terrible when I do so, simply because there's no better way)

Comment: @RayMairlot  you can add the combine XYZ node to your answer since it is available now