# Nested texture on all sides of cube

Tags: texturing, node-editor

I am a total beginner to Blender.

I want the checkered brick texture to be on all sides of the cube. How can I do this?

I have tried adding a texture coordinate with UV output connected to the brick texture's input vector.

Here is the rendered output and node setup:

[image: cube]

[image: nodes]

Comment: Have you tried unwrapping the cube as a cube projection?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has a rather simple solution.
You almost got it right on your first try.

[image]

You have to connect your UV coordinates.
Add a *Texture coordinate* node - use the UV output.
Add a *Mapping* node - use it to rotate the checker texture.

Connect them like this, and you're good to go.

[image]

[image]

Comment: That's a beautiful cube scene. Can you share the blend file?

Answer (score 5):

The Checker texture is 3D. It divides the given texture space into blocks. The Brick texture is 2D. It's calculated in U and V, but just projected through W.

So you can map the checker in a 3D space, (here, Object space) but the bricks need some kind of mapping onto 2D surfaces to look like bricks. The default UV map of a cube will do, here.

[image]

If you'd like some kind of procedural mapping that rotates the brick texture to line up with surfaces without an explicit UV map, you can use an approach something like [this one](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/113922/35559)

Comment: Thanks for posting your answer. I had no idea these textures work differently. Well, always learning :).

Comment: You can always do what you've done, and take a 2D slice at W=0 out of the checker texture.. I just thought it was an opportunity to show the difference.