# Bricktexture allignment on different Objects

Tags: cycles-render-engine, shaders

I wanted to make a House for my Art class and used the brick texture node with some extras to make a brick shader for the walls. Because the bricks didn't align correctly with the first object (House1) I added a Mapping and Texture coordinate node to adjust it. Now that i need to do the other side of the house the shader of the bricks is not aligned correctly and weirdly stretched. I thought that I could fix it by unwrapping the objects and then set the texture coordinate to UV, but it made it made it worse.
Thanks in advance.

Here's the Blend file: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1u0f0i5NZXxUbIkHjgmLmKPWjTaXAe_z9?usp=sharing

[image: Hope that this image portrays the problem well]

Comment: what you show is not what I see when I open your file, could you please simplify your file as much as possible (object + material) so that's easy to find where is the problem and how to fix it?

Comment: Sure, hope that this is simpler. I updated the file in the drive folder.

Comment: it's still not what you show on your picture, it must be because of my Blender version, i hope someone will help

Comment: I still use 2.82a, but thanks for trying to help

Comment: I solved the issue with the solution from this problem. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/112843/how-can-i-make-my-procedural-brick-texture-map-correctly-to-both-a-cube-and-cyli

Comment: oh ok, great then   ;)