# Brick texture stretches in vertical direction

Tags: texturing

I have extruded plane (texture is fine on it) edges 1 by 1, and applied a simple brick texture.
For some reason nor re-unwrapping nor applying transforms deals with the issue.
Normals are correct and making seams does nothing, even splitted or separated faces remain "untexturable".

[image]

[image]

Comment: could you please pack your image and share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Maybe you need to remove the old UV map. Go to the object data properties tab, got to UV maps, remove the one that's there, and unwrap again.

Comment: Ooops, I guess it's because of the material. Checker Texture and others work fine. But bricks don't for some reason.

Comment: Checker, and others, are 3D textures, the pattern on the surface is a result of a slice through a field of colors calculated from the XY _and_ Z location of the shading point in whatever space you have set up. The Bricks texture is 2D, it only uses X and Y. Typically,  you would give it a UV (XY) map to work with... but there are options, see [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/113922/35559), for example

Comment: @RobinBetts Thanks a lot
That's exactly what I needed. 
However, in my case it doesn't work with UV maps for some reason, as you can see.

Comment: For making it work with UVs add in a texture coordinate node before the texture and connect the UV to the vector input of the texture