# Brick Texture On Extruded Cylinder Shows All Mortar Color

Tags: modeling

Very new to Blender, so I'm not sure what to research for on this problem...

If I add a mesh/cylinder I can add brick texture, then get the texture to "wrap" (?) around the structure just fine, as in the bottom portion of this image

[image]

If I try to resize the cylider by extruding, the entire new surface reverts to the "mortar" color, as in the top portion of the above image.

The same thing happens if I add a circle and extrude that.

I have tried playing with every visible parameter for the Brick Texture node, but can't get the brick texture on an extruded section.

I'm trying to use extrudes so that I can utilize snap capabilities.

Any suggestions appreciated, including helping me understand where to look for myself

Thanks in advance

Comment: Also see: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/112843/how-can-i-make-my-procedural-brick-texture-map-correctly-to-both-a-cube-and-cyli/113922#113922

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### It's an UV map problem

You may have correctly unwrapped the cylinder (or used the default cylinder which comes already unwrapped) but unless you are using the brand new (2.90) 3D View Transform option, called **[Correct Face Attributes](https://s3.amazonaws.com/cgcookie-rails/uploads%2F1598382523436-NwyrEnxkVU.gif)**, which allows the transform tools to edit the UV’s and vertex colors of your mesh while you manipulate the model, **you'll have to unwrap the new faces too**.

The UV island for the interested faces is probably collapsed onto a single line in the UV editor, which falls in corrispondence if a mortar.

Comment: Very helpful. Now I understand how the only way I could get it to work at all was by using a default cylinder.  Now I know to research 3D View Transform and Correct Face Attributes.