# Repetitive texture on rounded corners

Tags: texturing

What is your best method for achieving repetitive textures wrapped around a rounded corner of a mesh, like in the image?

If your method avoids UV unwrapping or coding - even better! Thanks.[image]

Comment: If you're using bitmap textures, you have to use UVs, if you plan to keep this in blender you can use tiling procedural nodes without UVs, so can you clarify on what your plans are please

Comment: I'd like to wrap a beveled cube in a marble tile texture where the texture rounds the corners like in the image in this satisfying neat and accurate way. Have a look at D-tile website. thanks

Comment: Check out [this kind of answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/113922/35559)

Comment: @JKCapeTown I'm going to assume you're going to keep this in blender, as such you can use nodes for this, however I'd build substance in substance designer, and utilise planar UVs with tiling textures

Answer (score 0):

If you unwrap the mesh before any bevelling it should work, so if you unwrap the mesh and then add bevel, it would look fine.