# Correct map procedural brick texture on cube

Tags: cycles-render-engine, procedural, vector-mapping

Could somebody help my place texture to all sides of the box?
First I found topic on forum:[How can I make my procedural brick texture map correctly to both a cube and cylinder?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/112843/how-can-i-make-my-procedural-brick-texture-map-correctly-to-both-a-cube-and-cyli)
Then I made a nodeset:
[image: This is a nodeset]
I have correct textured view in Blender:
[image: Correct textured on view]
But rendered textures are incorrect:
[image: Inciorrect textures on render]
What am I doing wrong? I would be happy accept some help.

Comment: Hi :). Perhaps you have a second set of objects set to render with the old texture?

Comment: Hi, congrats on your first question here!  Some more info might be helpful, such as which version of Blender you're using.  Also, it's sometimes a good idea to post your blend file, or a truncated version of it that has the problem.  The Blender StackExchange has its own service to share blend files:  https://blend-exchange.com/help

Comment: Thank All! This nodeset https://i.imgur.com/4eoSaF9.jpg helped my. Its works.