# How would I be able to procedurally generate brick tiles like these?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor, photorealism

I am trying to replicate a pedestrian subway/walkway in my town and have come across an interesting brick texture I've been trying hours to replicate, the wall in question is:

[image: the wall in question]

This has been the closest I have got to replicating the wall but as you can see it's still not very close:

[image: replication of the wall]

Finally, this is my node layout:

[image: nodes]

Thank you all for the help, and I'd appreciate an explanation of how the nodes work if you manage to do an accurate replication :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a procedural brick texture for a simple building without object size changing the texture size?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/70444/how-to-create-a-procedural-brick-texture-for-a-simple-building-without-object-si)

Answer (score 1):

Three ideas, that might help here.

1. Don't underestimate good lighting. Use HDRIs, to add complex reflections.
2. Count your brick pattern :). It's 11 bricks high, Running Bond pattern, each brick roughly 1:3 ratio. Read more about the [Brick Texture node](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/textures/brick.html).
3. Add depth. Nothing is flat in the real world. Use *Bump* or *Displacement*, to make your material feel real.

*This material would look boring as hell without the HDRI lighting.*

[image]

*Count and measure the brick pattern :). It's not totally random, it has some rules.*

[image]

*Use at least a simple Bump map to add depth. While still pretty crude, it's better than nothing.*

[image]