# How can I achieve box projection with blend for procedural 2D textures using only nodes and without using UV map?

Tags: node-editor, procedural

How can I achieve exactly that mapping, without UV and with only nodes?
[image]

This is the closest that I achived. [image]

And it is not bad, but blending doesn't work. And it is very hard to come to a solution how to implement it in a performance efficient way.

Whole node set up.
[image]

Comment: No, I want the same effect only with procedural(2D, without Z axis) textures. @moonboots

Comment: oh ok sorry....

Comment: Maybe check out @Rich Sedman on triplanar mapping ([This answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/70607/35559) and its refs)

Comment: @RobinBetts Thank you, but projection on a sphere looks awful, with that solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

"Blend" is a 0-1 range value, with 0 corresponding to nearly no blend and 1 corresponding to a pretty loose blend.

Not appropriate for anything feeding displacement, as normal depends on displacement; if you need box mapped displacement, bake a UV mapped texture.

Can't really make out your nodes to see how similar that is to what you have.

Comment: Yeah. It is a very good solution. Thank you for your hard work to help me, I will try to go over nodes to understand decisions you made to solve this problem.