# Rotate texture to align with face normal

Tags: texturing, normals, procedural, vector

I have a multi-faceted object which is supposed to look like it is built out of brick.  I currently have it built as a single mesh and would prefer to keep it that way.

I need to brick on each face to appear aligned to the face, like it would be in real-life construction.  Of course I don't want it to look like someone cut the shape out of a uni-directional infinite slab of brick texture.

So I thought I'd be real clever and try to use the face normals as a reference to rotate and align the texture to the face.  But I'm having a tough time getting consistent results.

The screenshot below shows my object (yes, it's a fireplace).  For reference, I've placed a plane next to it which simply shows the unmodified brick texture.  I've also shown my current node setup to communicate my approach.

How can I accomplish what I'm trying to do here?

[image]

[image]

Comment: What are you concerned about?  The diagonals?  You're rotating in a diagonal axis (cross of world Z and normal.)  Get angle to world Y and rotate in world Z instead.  Will that work for XY planes?  No, those need to be handled separately (cross product of normal and world Z for those is 0 vector anyways.)  Or concerned about seams?  Seams are unavoidable-- think about the *center* of your rotation.  Solution?  This is a good example of why you want to UV map a mesh.  If you can't make a seamless, distortion free UV map, you can't make it any other way either.

Comment: You might be interested in [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/70607/35559)

Comment: @RobinBetts:  Yes, that is exactly what I needed.  I was able to complete my texture node setup by studying that answer and the others in that question.  Thank you!