# Shader Editor - Mapping Rotation by Face Normals

Tags: shaders, normals, geometry, shader-nodes

I want to somehow use an "Object" Texture Coordinate Mapping with Brick Texture (yes, exactly "object", i don't want to use uv)
So, how to use normals from faces to calculate normals for texture coordinate?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/70444/35559 might be relevant.. and other similar answers

Comment: Thanx, Robin!
Also, for others: you can check out the box mapping node by erindale that also can be useful 
erindale.gumroad.com/l/untiling