# Create grid material

Tags: materials

I found a material Im using to create a grid on my model, it works great on a plane but not on cubes and sphears. How do I get the grid to be on the sides also, not only on the top side of my spheare and cube.

My example blender file can be found here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UKQwDi8hKQIdpY5IhybQjTCoCeHOQk82/view?usp=sharing

Also, can I make the black on the grid transparant so the teture is visable.

[image: grid on top but not the sides]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/112843/how-can-i-make-my-procedural-brick-texture-map-correctly-to-both-a-cube-and-cyli https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/70444/how-to-create-a-procedural-brick-texture-for-a-simple-building-without-object-si