# Scale Independent Object Mapping for procedural textures

Tags: uv, procedural, texture-coordinates, vector-mapping, project

can someone please advise me how to get even mapping if I want to create procedural textures using noise and musgrave. I don't want to use UV or Generated mapping. I don't even want to manually adjust the scale in X,Y,Z to match the stretch. I want to create Object mapping so that it does not stretch in longer directions. I want to use universal mapping like projection on a cube. It should probably be a mathematical procedure with vectors. The closest other posts I found on this topic are this:

[How to create a procedural brick texture for a simple building without object size changing the texture size?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/70444/how-to-create-a-procedural-brick-texture-for-a-simple-building-without-object-si)

But that's not exactly it. Thanks for any help
George
[image]

Comment: Sorry if this question sounds stupid: when you want to "create object mapping", why not use the _Object_ output of the _Texture Coordinate_ node?

Comment: Good question. Picture with generated is confusing. It works the same. Same problem.

Comment: So you probably have scaled the object in _Object Mode_ and not applied the scale?

Comment: Yes, that is true. I know. But I wanted to make a fully procedural system Independent of the geometry itself, like cube projection with a default setup for every object. The result should be geometry, which you can edit and the texture is still in the same size. It could be useful for prepared bricks size for example. Thanks.