# Can I use object's Custom Properties inside Cycles materials?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials

I wonder if maybe the Attribute node in Cycles can bring in a Custom Property of an object.

I have a model that has an LED light, and I wish I could change the color of the LED on different instances of the model, without using different materials.

[image: Custom property]

[image: Atrribute node]

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3493/can-i-get-the-object-dimensions-in-cycles

Answer (score 4):

Since V2.92, Cycles and Eevee feature an [Attribute Node](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/input/attribute.html).

Add a Custom Property to your object.

[image]

Set the Type to *Object* and type in the name of your custom property.

[image]

These objects share the same material :

[image]

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to using the pass ID is using the object name and an OSL script. It is not very elegant either, but at least allows for setting multiple values. I have explained it [here](https://blenderartists.org/t/pass-object-custom-property-to-material-via-osl-script/1177984).

Comment: I upvoted your post. However, including a summary of the method (copy paste it maybe) would be great.

Answer (score 1):

Use the object's `pass ID`.

That's a less than elegant, jerry-jigged way of doing it, but I've managed to animate the emission of some cartoon stars independently with this, even they're sharing the same material.

[image: shader nodes]

I collect the objects pass ID with the Object Info node, then perform some operations on it so I can operate under an *arbitrarily defined* range of 100 to 110. You can use any range you want. Notice I have only 10 different brightness levels on my shader. If you need something smoother, get yourself a wider range.

After doing that, it's just a matter of setting the object's pass IDs and the material will react accordingly on a per-object basis. You can even **animate** them by hitting `I` on the `pass ID` field.

This approach has lot's of limitations, though:

- You'll waste some pass ID channels on this, and you'd better not use them elsewhere. Make sure you have them marked as used if you're on a larger project.
- You have a single channel to transfer information, so no complicated
  things like colors can be properly and freely animated.
- Also, the pass ID is an integer, and that means either using a large enough
  range if you need fine detail or going for a coarser animation.

But it's the best I've found until now.

Answer (score 0):

There's a patch that adds exactly this functionality in the works:

https://developer.blender.org/D2057

Comment: note that this has been in the tracker unchanged since juli 2016.