# Blinking Emission Objects

Tags: animation

I don't know how to make Emission objects have a flickering animation. I'm trying to make it like those broken gas station signs that flicker. I've looked through the internet and they give me little details. Help a brother out?

Comment: somehow related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47375/how-to-control-many-tiny-lights/47385#47385

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways you could go about this:

1. Animate Emission Strength (This is the better option)
2. Using an Animated Texture

   1. Hover of the strength of your emission shader and press <kbd>I</kbd>. Then skip a couple of frames and make strength 0 and again press <kbd>I</kbd>. Keep on doing this and adjust as you wish to get the wanted result.
   2. The texture could be made inside Blender using the compositor or in Photoshop (requires you to do it frame by frame).