# How do i tell blender to render image after 3 sec everytime?

Tags: rendering

I want to animate a 100 light which turn on one after other.
How do i dothat in blender.

Please help.
Thanks

Comment: I think you will need to add some more details to get a helpful answer, not sure exactly what you are trying to do

Comment: To get a proper answer please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your post and add more details to the question and clarify the title. Please specify what render engine you are using and add an image that gives an idea of what your scene looks like.

Comment: Please don't close the questions before giving the OP a chance to clarify.

Comment: Probably related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47375/how-to-control-many-tiny-lights/47385#47385