# console warning: "Too many lights in the scene !!!"

Tags: lighting, error

Every time I switch back to my Layout workspace I get a flood of messages saying:

> Too many lights in the scene !!!

Everything seems to be rendering fine.   I do have some simulated "LED light arrays" in my scene.  Is this a serious problem or should I ignore this?   How many lights are too many?

[image]

Comment: @susu thanks i was mostly using Cycles to render but Eevee for VP-shading mode and I see that is what causes the warning. Thanks for pointing out the Eevee limitation in documentation, I guess it might be difficult to know which of the 128 are used or perhaps the first 128 it finds in the blend data.

Comment: (I slightly enjoy the fact that some blender developer decided to use three exclamation marks for this warning. Almost as if using one ! is simply not enough here :))

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For questions like this please indicate what render engine you are using. Eevee has a limit of 128 lights in a scene.

Read:

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/eevee/limitations.html

Also, for simulated LED arrays you might want to consider a single texture as part of an emission shader.

[How to give an image or video a TV screen effect?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39508/how-to-give-an-image-or-video-a-tv-screen-effect)

and

[How to control many tiny lights](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47375/how-to-control-many-tiny-lights/47385#47385)