# Pixelated screen look

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I want something to have this look (the eyes)[image]

But i do not know how to get this look. I looked it up multiple times and it shows how to fix grainy and pixelated pictures. Please help! It would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried manually drawing a texture like that in an external image editing application, like Photoshop, GIMP, Inkscape or Illustrator? You can also manually model it with small circle shaped objecs

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39508/how-to-give-an-image-or-video-a-tv-screen-effect

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to give an image or video a TV screen effect?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39508/how-to-give-an-image-or-video-a-tv-screen-effect)