# Apply mask in material with condition

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials, image

I'm trying to do a led panel in Cycles. The "leds" have a Image displaced by object position.

I would like to filter te color of the led if in the object-material is more or less white region, to get the pixel effect.
The mask-image is a black and white jpg.

Any idea?
Thank you!

[image]
[image]

Comment: Related? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39508/how-to-give-an-image-or-video-a-tv-screen-effect