# Is possible to render different objects to different color channels with Cycles shader (w/o compositor)?

Tags: compositing-nodes, shaders

I have three texture mapped objects in a scene. The rendering of each needs to effect just one color channel
of the final image. I’m currently able to accomplish this by assigning each to a separate render layer
and combining them the compositor. Is it possible to achieve this with just shader logic?

The hope is to produce a reasonable looking image in the 3D view.

The objects are currently using Emissive Transparent materials to give “Shadeless” behavior.

An example blender file is available at: https://github.com/BrianSwift/JunoCam/blob/master/Juno3D/P00_102c.blend

Additional solutions that work in BI or EEVEE would are also appreciated, but Cycles
is needed because BI doesn’t have the equirectangular (panoramic) camera model.

**Edit**
So, it's been over 3 years and I'm upgrading my workflow from 2.79b to 3.2, just adding this bump to see if anyone has suggestion for alternate/better way to accomplish task.

Comment: maybe related? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39508/how-to-give-an-image-or-video-a-tv-screen-effect/39509#39509

Comment: FWIW, in Apple's SceneKit I get the desired effect by setting each materials colorBufferWriteMask property which is basically exposing the functionality of OpenGL's glColorMask() render state setting function. Searching Blender's source code shows the few calls to glColorMask() all have constant parameters, so there is no method for the users to specify the mask.