# How to setup a material with a Photo and Emission to mimic a TV screen with Eevee?

Tags: materials

I have tried many things but I am not a master at Material nodes :frowning:
I am doing a Non-Realistic animation, kind of cartoonish.

Thanks guys

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39508/how-to-give-an-image-or-video-a-tv-screen-effect/39509#39509

Comment: That did it, thank you susu :)

Comment: mark the question as duplicate then.