# Procedural polka dot pattern with cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, shaders, osl

I would like to generate a polka dot pattern using material nodes.
In the meantime I found [this script](http://blendersushi.blogspot.com.es/2013/08/osl-disk-grid.html) which seems to achieve exactly what I want.

However, when I create a script node, link to the script internally and pipe the color output to a diffuse shader, my object is rendered black.
Has something changed in Blender preventing this to work? Because I get no errors whatsoever.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

OSL is nice but does not run on GPU which limits performance. The **Polka pattern** is not that hard to construct **procedurally using nodes**:

Start with a simple dot - a spherical gradient with Color Ramp:

[image]

With the ColorRamp you can control the size of the dot.

Next create [tiling for procedural textures](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/26703/7777), but staggered. Extra is a Mapping node to control the size of the whole pattern:

[image]

That's it. You can also map it with [Cylindrical or Spherical projection](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/45169/7777).

Comment: Wow, that's a great tip indeed! I was looking for something like this rather than to start scripting. Thanks.

Comment: This is really cool! You might consider adapting it to http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3491/dot-matrix-display-in-cycles. I didn't know about the "Gradient Texture" node when I wrote my answer there.

Comment: (Well, to be more precise, I didn't know about the "spherical" option.)

Answer (score 6):

The shader script you linked to is written in [Open Shading Language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Shading_Language) (OSL).  In order to use an OSL shader in Cycles you have to check *Open Shading Language* under the *Render* rollout of the *Render* properties panel.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Didn't really notice that checkbox until now.

Answer (score 3):

This is a special case of a previous question: **[Dot matrix display in Cycles?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3491/dot-matrix-display-in-cycles)**

Here is an example of the possible output:

[image: Plane with the (old) gandalf3 logo in glowing polka dots]

To create “plain” polka dots, you can

- just use a solid color instead of an image texture;
- use a diffuse shader instead of emission for the primary output; and/or
- mix with a different diffuse shader instead of transparency if you want the unoccupied regions to be opaque.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Polka pattern simple]

Hello there, so I just discoverd this method of making a polka design pattern that you can use later to mask into anything, I am not a shader pro, but managed to make this short and easy one, play around with Scale value abd vornoir texture values to change the size, its pretty broken and I dont know how it works but it works and prolly get your work done if you lookin for something similar

[image: here is the simple node setup]