# How to map one image across multiple objects

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials

I am looking for an older post on here, but I can't find it.

I can't recall the exact question, but essentially a user asked how to cast an image across an entire array of objects with it automatically fitting to the objects. A person responded and the main image they used to answer was using a blender logo in many different shapes and sizes. I am hoping to find the original post. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Dot matrix display in Cycles?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3491/dot-matrix-display-in-cycles?noredirect=1&lq=1)

This is the thread I was looking for. The term I had been thinking of was "Dot Matrix"